# FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK error integrating android native library in react native

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-intent

I'm trying to integrate a native payment library in a react native application.

The library requires an view setup like this to process the pay result.

The library raises next error

`Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?`

I don't know if my configuration is wrong, the native library demo application works fine. :(
The pay response intent tries load the activity but apparently it can't find it.

**Update**
The library function that fails is:

```java
String appId = context.getPackageName() + "." + callbackSchema;
Intent intent = new Intent(appId);
intent.putExtra(ConstantUtil.RETURNED_JSON_KEY,json);
context.startActivity(intent); // <- this call raises the error
```

**Update**
Finally I made it work. I was passing context like that:

```java
getReactApplicationContext()
```

I solved it passing context like that:

```java
getCurrentActivity()
```

In debug, I got this values:

[image]

but the error still raising :(

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I made it work. I was passing context like that:

```java
getReactApplicationContext()
```

I solved it passing context like that:

```java
getCurrentActivity()
```